# MySql stored procedure error [ERROR 1338 (42000): Cursor declaration after handler declaration]

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am reading an article on stored procedures and this is the code:

```
delimiter //

create procedure largest_order(out largest_id int) 
begin
  declare this_id int;
  declare this_amount float;
  declare l_amount float default 0.0;
  declare l_id int;

  declare done int default 0;
  declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done = 1;
  declare c1 cursor for select orderid, amount from orders;

  open c1;
  repeat
    fetch c1 into this_id, this_amount;
    if not done then
      if this_amount > l_amount then
        set l_amount=this_amount;
        set l_id=this_id;
      end if;
    end if;
   until done end repeat; 
  close c1;

  set largest_id=l_id;

end
//

delimiter ;
```

I am using a simple database named "mydatabase". After running the above code it gives me this error: `ERROR 1338 (42000): Cursor declaration after handler declaration`
What is wrong and how can I fix it?

This is my first time working with stored procedures.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per MySql [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/cursors.html):

> Cursor declarations must appear before handler declarations and after
>   variable and condition declarations.

So I updated the code as follows:

```
delimiter //

create procedure largest_order(out largest_id int) 
begin
  declare this_id int;
  declare this_amount float;
  declare l_amount float default 0.0;
  declare l_id int;

  -- 1. cursor finished/done variable comes first
  declare done int default 0;
  -- 2. the curser declaration and select
  declare c1 cursor for select orderid, amount from orders;
  -- 3. the continue handler is defined last
  declare continue handler for sqlstate '02000' set done = 1;


  open c1;
  repeat
    fetch c1 into this_id, this_amount;
    if not done then
      if this_amount > l_amount then
        set l_amount=this_amount;
        set l_id=this_id;
      end if;
    end if;
   until done end repeat; 
  close c1;

  set largest_id=l_id;

end
//

delimiter ;
```

And now works fine.